# Spring-Data-Rest: Spring Data Book Example failing when upgrading to spring-data-rest-webmvc 2.0.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am upgrading the version of spring-data-rest-webmvc (from 1.1.0.M1 to 2.0.0.RELEASE) and spring-data-jpa (from 1.3.0.RELEASE to 1.5.0.RELEASE) in spring-data-book example given in tutorial section of spring-data-rest and spring-data-jpa projects homepage. However, I am getting the below error:

```
07-May-2014 17:08:56.176 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive C:\Software\tomcat\webapps\Tst1.war
2014-05-07 17:08:59,353 DEBUG itory.config.RepositoryComponentProvider: 264 - Identified candidate component class: file [C:\Software\tomcat\webapps\Tst1\WEB-INF\classes\com\oreilly\springdata\rest\order\OrderRepository.class]
2014-05-07 17:08:59,364 ERROR pringframework.web.context.ContextLoader: 324 - Context initialization failed
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.processCommonDefinitionAnnotations(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AnnotatedBeanDefinition;)V from class org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryComp
        at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(RepositoryComponentProvider.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.getCandidates(RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-commons-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.getRepositoryConfigurations(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:54) ~[spring-data-commons-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:78) ~[spring-data-commons-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImport(ConfigurationClassParser.java:340) ~[spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:232) ~[spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:153) ~[spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:139) ~[spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:282) ~[spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223) ~[spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630) ~[spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461) ~[spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) ~[spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) ~[spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4828) [catalina.jar:8.0.0-RC5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5276) [catalina.jar:8.0.0-RC5]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.0-RC5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726) [catalina.jar:8.0.0-RC5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702) [catalina.jar:8.0.0-RC5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:698) [catalina.jar:8.0.0-RC5]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:968) [catalina.jar:8.0.0-RC5]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1742) [catalina.jar:8.0.0-RC5]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
```

Below is my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.oreilly.springdata</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-book</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>spring-data-book-rest-test1</artifactId>
    <name>Spring Data Book - REST exporter</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data REST -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.M1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency-->

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId> 
                <version>3.2.1.ga</version> -->

            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Database -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Web -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>Tst1</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.0.0.RC2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-libs-milestone</id>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was jar dependency issue.

After Upgrade below is how my pom.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
            http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.oreilly.springdata</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-book</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>spring-data-book-rest-test1</artifactId>
    <name>Spring Data Book - REST exporter</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data REST -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId> 
            <version>1.1.0.M1</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version> 
         </dependency -->

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                 <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId> 
                 <version>3.2.1.ga</version> -->

            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>Tst1</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.0.0.RC2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-libs-milestone</id>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```